# MVC3: Multiple button with ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view which has two button and bind with a model (generated by GET request - /User/Edit/1). I have used BeginForm without any action name specified as I want to use Model Validation. I have assign action (URL) using ajax configuration to “Close” button. When I run my application and pressed Close button, firstly, it perform an action successfully using ajax configuration ( close data entry ) and then perform action for POST request (/User/Edit/1). I want to know, why second action performed when I pressed close button and how can I stop to perform ??

Partial View: _Record.cshtml

---

---

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <hr />
    <p>
        <fieldset style="display:inline-block">
            <legend>User</legend>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: right; padding-left: 20px;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.first_name, 
new { style = "width:270px;", maxlength = 30 })
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.first_name)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
    *****
    *****

            <p>
       <input type="submit" value="Save" style="float: right" />
       <input type="submit" value="Close" onclick="Close()" style="float: right" />
            ?</p>
        </fieldset>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    </p>
}
```

Comment: have you stepped through the code with Visual Studio's debugger? It also might help us if we could see the Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input type="submit" means that when you press this button you are submitting the model in the view back to the controller to post it.  Remove type="submit"

Comment: Another option is to goto your POST method and test a value on the sending HTML element such as passing input_element to the POST method and testing it's value

Comment: Cool... I replace type="submit" to type="button" and it works fine.. thank you soo much ... :)